# Adding multi-language option to a Qt app with hard-coded text

Tags: c++, qt5, multilingual

I'm a beginner in Qt. I have an app designed using Qt which has multiple windows with each consisting of several labels with hard coded text. What would be the easiest way to add multi language support for this app? Which built in Qt objects/functions I should use?

My current idea is to maybe create a separate xml file including the text for all labels for a language. Then once the user selects a language icon from the menu, load the relevant xml file. But I have no idea how to do this. Any help would be highly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
I have tried to implement the example given [here](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application#File_system_structure_of_the_application:). But it throws the following error and I can't fix it. *'class Ui::MainWindow' has no member named 'menuLanguage'*

QActionGroup* langGroup = new QActionGroup(ui->menuLanguage);

Comment: I'd just follow the docs and do as they suggest.

Answer (score 4):

Try  [Qt Linguist](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlinguist-index.html):

I made you a simple example:

.pro

```
TRANSLATIONS += translation_fa.ts
```

.h

```
#include <QTranslator>
QTranslator translator;
```

.cpp

```
if(translator.load("E:/Qt/Linguist/linguist/translation_fa.qm"))
    qDebug()<<"successfully load qm file.";
else
    qDebug()<<"problem in load qm file.";


// change language to second language
qApp->installTranslator(&translator);

// change language to default language
qApp->removeTranslator(&translator);
```

Don't forget to use [Qt Linguist Tools](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/linguist-translators.html).

[image]

This is a sample project for your question on [github download here.](https://github.com/FarhadProfessional/Qt-Linguist)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Qt has translation support. Look into [Qt Linguist](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlinguist-index.html)

Basically, you mark all you hard coded texts with a call to `QObject::tr`, e.g.

```
lbl->setText(tr("My text to translate"));
```

Qt Linguist parses all source files and UI forms for such calls (using lupdate.exe) and builds a `ts` file. With the Qt Linguist GUI application, you can translate them. With lrelease you create a `qm` file that will be loaded at runtime, and automatically translate the texts

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

Qt has built in functions for managing multiple languages:

see: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application

Research lupdate lrelease and linguist